# Occurrence count based SELECT without using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a database table where each row contains information about computer hardware purchases, which looks like this:

```
| clientID | typeOfDevice | transactionDate |
```

`typeOfDevice` contains a string with the type of device that the customer bought.

Using SQL, how can I find every client who bought `Laptop` at least 2 times and at most one `PC`, without using `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can do it using correlated sub-queries:

```
SELECT clientID
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT clientID,
         (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM mytable AS t2
          WHERE t1.clientID = t2.clientID AND
                typeOfDevice = 'Laptop') AS laptops,
         (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM mytable AS t2
          WHERE t1.clientID = t2.clientID AND
                typeOfDevice = 'PC') AS pcs              
  FROM mytable AS t1 ) AS t
WHERE t.laptops >= 2 AND t.pcs <=1;
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d7792/2)

Answer (score 0):

`SQL Server` solution using windowed functions:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT clientId
   ,COUNT(CASE WHEN typeOfDevice = 'laptop' THEN 1 END) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY clientId) AS laptop
   ,COUNT(CASE WHEN typeOfDevice = 'PC' THEN 1 END) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY clientId) AS PC
  FROM table_name
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE laptop >= 2 AND PC <=1;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/387977)**</kbd>